# React Native Multiple command produce same file

Tags: react-native

I tried to build a react native app for iOS and I hit this error:

```
Build system information
error: Multiple commands produce '/Volumes/Data/sources/react-native/test/ios/build/test/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.app/Zocial.ttf':
1) Target 'test' (project 'test') has copy command from '/Volumes/Data/sources/react-native/test/node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts/Zocial.ttf' to '/Volumes/Data/sources/react-native/test/ios/build/test/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/test.app/Zocial.ttf'
2) That command depends on command in Target 'test' (project 'test'): script phase “[CP] Copy Pods Resources”
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try deleting the build folder in ios directory and rebuilding your app again. It might solve this issue

Comment: too bad it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have installed some library with fonts that iOS don't have linked. Try this:

1. Create an empty dir in your project to store some future useful fonts (for example "Nunito" family font). I suggest create `fonts` folder into `assets` --> `assets/fonts`
2. Create a new file named `react-native.config.js` in the root of your project and add into it the following:

```
module.exports = {
    project: {
        ios: {},
        android: {}
    },
    assets: ['./src/assets/fonts/'],
};
```

3. In your project dir run `react-native link`
4. Go to `ios` dir (`cd ios`) and run `pod update`
5. Build

Especial thanks to Alex Biddle: https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-add-custom-fonts-to-your-react-native-project-c64305281b9

Answer (score 0):

I had this error with react-native-vector-icons installed after I executed `react-native link`. My solution was to remove fonts copying from XCode Build Phases.

[image: XCode Build Phases]